# .NET 3.5 ASP.NET project has its XmlSerializer build with .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I got a very old asp.net project, build upon the .NET Framework 3.5 version. One of the project (the website itself, let's call it "Web") got a Web Reference to another project (the service backend).

When I publish "Web", I got a auto-generated dll called "Web.XmlSerializer" built, which upon closer inspection is built targeting .NET Framework 4.0, despite the project targeting .NET Framework 3.5, which makes the website fail to load on the IIS App Pool.

A colleague built with the very same source code, and ended up with the same auto-generated dll, but this time build with the .NET Framework 3.5.

We both have mostly the same tools installed (VS 2019, VS 2022, but he got VS 2012 installed and I don't). We both built with VS 2022.

So why that specific dll decided to generate with a totally different CLR that its parent project? Is there a setting that may influence such builds ?

Comment: `Web Reference` means the obsolete ASMX web services stack that was replaced by WCF around 2007. What you got is a client proxy for that service, not just an autogenerated serializer. They're still available in .NET Framework 4.x. BTW 4.0 is itself discontinued since 2016. The oldest supported .NET Framework version is 4.6.2

Comment: What's the question anyway? How to make discontinued versions work? Or how to make the projects work on a *supported* SDK and runtime?

Comment: The question is, why is it built with .NET 4.0 instead of .NET 3.5, considering the project it is generated for targets .NET Framework 3.5.

I know very well those version aren't supported anymore, but the client don't want to pay for an upgrade, despite all the implications, thus we are stuck with that. I can't ask MS for help, that's why I'm here.

Comment: You'll have to start by understanding what web services are. The client code is generated by your IDE, not the server. It doesn't matter whether it's ASMX or WCF, or some other SOAP service written in Java. The IDE *or the svcutil tool) retrieves the service's description and builds the client code. VS 2022 doesn't install support for 3.5 precisely because it's no longer supported. It may be available as an extra standalone feature during installetion

Comment: I'm not a newbie to .NET development, I know very well how it works. What surprised me was that despite the main DLL being built without problem while targeting .NET 3.5, a DLL in particular, that according to my google-fu is an automatically generated one, when using web references, decides to build targeting .NET 4.0 instead of the .NET version the project explicitly targets.

But you are right about VS 2022 .NET 3.5 support. I supposed that installing the SDK would have sufficed, but I was wrong. After installing the package, it works as expected. Feel free to post that as answer.

Comment: The problem, unfortunately, wasn't that .NET Framework 3.5 wasn't enabled in Windows, but rather that the .NET Framework 3.5 support bits weren't installed in VS. That's why the build itself succeeded, as MSBuild had access to the SDK, but VS didn't have the bits required to generate 3.5 code, thus falling back to .NET 4.0.

Comment: @Dremor Hi, I posted your comment as an answer. You can mark it so that it can help more people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the .NET Framework 3.5 support bits weren't installed in VS. That's why the build itself succeeds, because MSBuild has access to the SDK, but VS doesn't have the necessary bits to build the 3.5 code, so it falls back to .NET 4.0.

[image]